# How do you initialize template class members that uses other template classes?

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays, template-classes

I'm having trouble correctly setting up and accessing my member functions of a class. This node class is being used to build a Max Heap Tree. However, when the tree is being initialized, I'm getting garbage data and not what I am initializing it to.

```
#ifndef HEAPNODE_H_INCLUDED
#define HEAPNODE_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

template <class Type> class HeapNode {
private:
    int key;
    Type value;
public:
    HeapNode(int key, Type const &value) {
        this->key = key;
        this->value = value;
    }

    // Returns the key of the node
    int getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    // Returns the value of the node
    Type getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    // Displays the node
    void displayNode() {
        cout << "Key: " << key << "\tValue: " << value << endl;
    }
};

#endif
```

Here is the class that builds my Heap Tree. I've tried setting the initializations in the constructor every which way, and I'm still getting junk data. In addition, I set the constructor to take an integer, but when I'm creating a tree in my driver program, it won't let me put an argument for it which initiates an array of that size.

```
#ifndef MAXHEAPTREE_H_tINCLUDED
#define MAXHEAPTREE_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "HeapNode.h"
using namespace std;

template <class Type> class MaxHeapTree {
private:
    HeapNode<Type> *array;
    HeapNode<Type> *root;
    int elementSize;
    int height;
    int leafCounter;
public: 
    // Constructor
    MaxHeapTree(int n = 10) : elementSize(0), height(0), leafCounter(0) {
        this->elementSize = elementSize;
        this->height = height;
        this->leafCounter = leafCounter;
        HeapNode<Type> *array = new HeapNode<Type>[n];
    }

    // Destructor
    ~MaxHeapTree();

    void arrayDisplay() {
        cout << "Original array size: " << sizeof(array)/4 << endl;
    }

    // Returns the number of elements in the tree
    int getSize() {
        return elementSize;
    }

    // Returns the height of the tree
    int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    // Returns the number of leaves in the tree
    int leaves() {
        return leafCounter;
    }

    int countLines(const string fileName) {
        string line;
        int lineCount = 0;

        ifstream myFile (fileName.c_str());
        if (myFile.is_open()) {
            while (getline(myFile, line)) {
                lineCount++;
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "Error opening file" << endl;
        }
        myFile.close();
        return lineCount;
    }

    // Reads structure from a text file and builds a max heap
    void buildTree(const string fileName) {
        string line;
        string key;
        string value;
        int lines = countLines(fileName);
        int i = 0;
        cout << "Lines: " << lines << endl;
        HeapNode<Type> *newArray[lines];
        cout << "Size of newArray: " << sizeof(newArray)/4 << endl;

        ifstream myFile (fileName.c_str());
        if (myFile.is_open()) {
            while (getline(myFile, line)) {
                key = line.substr(0, 1);
                int x = atoi(key.c_str());
                value = line.substr(1);

                HeapNode<Type> *hNode = new HeapNode<Type>(x, value);

                newArray[i] = hNode;
                cout << "newArray[" << i << "] = ";
                newArray[i]->displayNode();
                i++;
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "2 - Error opening file." << endl;
        }
        myFile.close();
    }
};

#endif
```

Comment: Note that array is a pointer, so sizeof(array) will return a constant (4 or 8 depending on whether compiled to 64 bit) regardless of n. Also you should delete[] array in ~MaxHeapTree().

Comment: In your `MaxHeapTree<>` constructor, this line: `HeapNode<Type> *array = new HeapNode<Type>[n];` is the issue. You are not initializing the `MaxHeapTree<>` data member called `array`, you're initializing a new local variable. Furthermore, you leak memory every time an instance is constructed.

Comment: @user2296177 How would that explain why elementSize, height, and leafCounter are giving junk data though, in addition to array?

Comment: I notice you're including `<array>` but not using `std::array`?

Comment: @XerenNarcy Yes, I thought that I needed it use sizeof(array)

Comment: I don't even know how you're able to instantiate your class since your destructor isn't even defined. Are you using `MaxHeapTree<> x = new MaxHeapTree<>;`?

Comment: @user2296177
I was using `MaxHeap<string> *heapTree1;`
I just changed it to `MaxHeapTree<string> *heapTree1 = new MaxHeapTree<string>(12);`
And now it initializes those elements to 0

Comment: That doesn't create an instance of your heap tree, that simply creates a uninitialized pointer to one... since the pointer is uninitialized, it points to a random memory location which you are accessing and invoking undefined behaviour. Please get a book from here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list. You have many more issues with your code.

Answer (score 0):

> How do you initialize template class members that uses other template classes?

In the same way you initialize members of non templates that don't use other templates.

> when the tree is being initialized, I'm getting garbage data and not what I am initializing it to.
>
> I was using `MaxHeap<string> *heapTree1;`

Well, there's your problem. Apparently you never created an instance of `MaxHeap<string>`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. I did initialize it by `MaxHeapTree<string> *heapTree1;`